# Create WiFi Sync for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, backup, wifi, port

For an iPhone app I need a web access/server to sync the Core Data database with the computer. So I can backup and replace it. But how can I create a port or something like this which can be called with the Mac or PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For wifi sync you can use synchronous BSD sockets. Through which you can do your data sync.

Comment: Thank you. It's CFSocket right? Is there any tutorial about this?

Comment: CFSocket is also BSD socket, but simple C sockets you can use for sync purpose.